# IIS 7.5 Accept Header MIME type not set correctly for most file types

Tags: webkit, types, mime, iis-7.5

Currently, all our headers are set to "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/sml;q=0.9, */*; q=0.8". It would seem from looking at this that our accept headers are not being set correctly in IIS 7. This is the setting for images, .json, everything else.

Is this correct, or is this incorrect? In webkit browsers, we are getting an 'warning' with links to jpeg files that the browser is sent a MIME type of image/jpeg but is interpreting the file as text/xhtml :"Resource interpreted as document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg."

This is leading to issues with a jQuery plugin, Shadowbox, not working as it should in webkit browsers (the browsers links to the images with its default behaviour as well as the shadowbox behaviour, so it sends you to a new page and then when you click back the images pops up as it should in a modal window.). It would seem that webkit is prioritizing the accept header over the received content-type when it attempts to display/process the file in question.

Any thoughts about what is going on, and if this is an issue with our implementation of IIS? Click on any of the markers at www.pomona.edu/tour and then an image icon within to replicate the warning through a console in any webkit browser.

Thanks,

Rory

Answer (score 0):

That does not sound like any known issue in IIS, you can run:
appcmd list config -section:staticContent
And that will show you the content types that IIS will generate. Are you sure those are not being generated by your application (or some kind of dynamic content like PHP/ASP.NET/ASP, etc)?